# C++: DLL with memory mapped file

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I have an DLL that might get called by multiple applications at the same time.
This DLL memory-maps a file.

I have 2 questions:

1) Each application will create its own instance of the DLL, right?
And thus, the file will be memory-mapped multiple times

2) If this is true, I don't understand what is happening here:

a) Application A calls the DLL.
b) Application B calls the DLL.
c) I quit application A, and the DLL will unmap the file.
d) Application B calls the DLL, and the memory-mapped file is not available anymore, and the call fails.

I don't understand this. 
Does anybody do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your assumption from 1) is false. A dll is by definition shared; both applications are using the same dll instance, so when you release the file in one application, it won't be available to the others.

To get around your issue, you should implement some reference counting mechanism in order to unmap the file only when no process is using it.

**Edit**: @sumeet is right. Each process has its own address space; when two processes load the same dll, they might share its read-only data for increased efficiency, but their writable data is local to each process. Nevertheless, a memory-mapped file is a kernel object, like semaphores, pipes and shared memory. Thus, if you unmap it in a process, you unmap it for all.

**Edit2**: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa366537) (Remarks section):

> Multiple processes can share a view of the same file by either using a
> single shared file mapping object or creating separate file mapping
> objects backed by the same file. A single file mapping object can be
> shared by multiple processes through inheriting the handle at process
> creation, duplicating the handle, or opening the file mapping object
> by name. For more information, see the CreateProcess, DuplicateHandle
> and OpenFileMapping functions.
>
> [...]
>
> Mapped views of a file mapping object maintain internal references to
> the object, and a file mapping object does not close until all
> references to it are released. Therefore, to fully close a file
> mapping object, an application must unmap all mapped views of the file
> mapping object by calling UnmapViewOfFile and close the file mapping
> object handle by calling CloseHandle. These functions can be called in
> any order.

First of all, from the first paragraph, how is each app initializing the view?
From the second paragraph, I gather that calling `UnmapViewofFile` and `CloseHandle` from each app will release all references to the memory file, and then Windows will automatically release the associated resources (i.e. he keeps the reference count, you don't need to do it).
Post your memory mapping initialization and shutdown code for both apps.

Comment: I did not downvote it. Wonder why it was downvoted. Can you tell me a sample for a reference counter?

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. Each process using that Dll will have their own copy of global and static variables.

Comment: @tmighty: Which Windows functions are you using to map and unmap the file? I think the mechanism I mentioned might already be built into the Windows API.

Comment: CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile and UnmapViewOfFile and CloseHandle

Comment: Should I use _Module.GetLockCount() as a reference counter?

Comment: And what should I do to check if my file is already mapped? Should I simply say static bool bDone=false; if (!bDone)... etc.???

Comment: No; read my edit. Each process has its own copy of static variables. let me look around the MSDN a bit and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @tmighty, check Edit2

Comment: @dario_ramos Thank you so much. The DLLs are instantiated by the Microsoft SAPI engine. I don't have any insights on how SAPI does it. In my applications I only reference the SAPI. I will try to put some messageboxes on which instance of the DLL creates a map and which releases it. Something is strange. Some instances clearly should have a view but they don't. I will first try to find out a bit more by myself. The answer regarding the instanciation already helped me much. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to tell the solution: I mapped the file to void*                   m_pVoiceData; and I declared it in global.h instead of in the COM object. I think that was the reason why the memory mapping was not correctly taken care of correctly. Now that it is a private member of the COM class, it works.